# Display the top five (5) drivers (id and name) with the most delivery. (Use: Inline View and JOIN)

Tags: sql, database

Display the top five (5) drivers (id and name) with the most delivery.  (Use:  Inline View and JOIN)

From the tables:

Relational Schema

Driver (driver_id, driver_name, driver_dob, driver_phone)

Delivery (driver_id, store_id, prod_id, delivery_date, delivery_qty, delivery_charge)

Store (store_id, store_location, store_ytdsale)

Product (prod_id, prod_description, prod_price)

Comment: What have you tried ? Where did you get stuck ? Stackoverflow is not a homework writing service

Comment: People are happy to *help* you, but that's hard if you don't show any initiative. Start by providing a reproducible example and googling how to ask a question on stack overflow.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.